# devise undefined method `first_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So, I'm using devise for User authentification for a rails app. I wish to add First Name and Last Name to the devise users. So, I created new columns to the Users database. Unfortunately, I'm getting "undefined method `first_name' " when I try my form. Here is the form:

```
        <h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.first_name :first_name, autofocus: true %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= f.last_name :last_name, autofocus: true %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I confirmed that the database columns were actually added by using the console. I typed

user = User.new into the console and got the following:

```
    "=> #<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil> "
```

When I type user.first_name, the console returns nil (which is good, as no errors are returned, so the columns were indeed added to the database). What is going on? What are possible fixes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> undefined method 'first_name'

In your case,the error is due to this line

```
<%= f.first_name :first_name, autofocus: true %>
```

This is supposed to be like this

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
```

And also this line

```
<%= f.last_name :last_name, autofocus: true %>
```

has to be changed to the same to avoid another error

```
<%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %>
```

You are using **`attribute names`** instead of **`text_field`**,so is the error.

Have a look at these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)** for the available **`form_helpers`** and their usage.It would be very useful.